# What is yoga samadhi?

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras

What does yoga samadhi mean? Are there still any people who are capable of doing yoga samadhi?  Does yoga samadhi mean that a person can go into samadhi on a pre-chosen date? How much time does it take to go into that state? Is it not similar to Jeeva Samadhi?

Jeeva samadhi means where a person lively goes to Vrindavana and covers his body completely inside a closed room.

Yoga samadhi means that a person on a pre-chosen auspicious date puts prana in shironaadi or in his navel and goes into samadhi state.

Recently I came across a swamiji named "Kashi Nayana" who lived for 100 years and and went into yoga samadhi on Dattatreya Jayanthi on 6th December, 1995. So can one choose a date and can go into yoga samadhi? Can they come back to normal when they want? and do they not need oxygen in that state?

I heard people can die of hanging, taking poison, jumping from top of a building etc. i.e by harming themselves but this concept looks different where a person does not harm himself and can die intentionally.